# Como detectar Instabilidade na rede com C#

Tags: c#, winforms, servidor

Tenho um sistema WinForms onde as pastas que esse sistema gera e utiliza fica em um servidor, porém existem algumas rotinas desse sistema que ficam criando vários PDF's no servidor, e quando ocorre qualquer instabilidade na rede ele não cria alguns PDF's. 
Gostaria de saber se existe algum Framework que detecta instabilidade ou queda na rede e avisa o usuário ou gerencie isso, alguém já ouviu falar de alguma coisa do tipo.
Se no momento que o sistema estiver utilizando o servidor a rede cair ou travar qualquer coisa a rotina irá avisar ou esperar para gerar quando voltar ao normal.

Comment: O framework para isso é o próprio .NET. O que você pode fazer é try-catch toda vez que for salvar os arquivos (você provavelmente já faz algum tratamento dessa forma).

Comment: Você também pode utilizar um temporizador para fazer um ping no servidor de dez em dez segundos, e subir um alerta caso não o alcance.

Comment: Atualmente eu utilizo o `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` para justamente fazer um ping no servidor, e só continuo caso o `Address` for diferente de `null`.

Comment: Cria uma fila de requisições de geração de arquivos, e enquanto o arquivo não for gerado com sucesso você fica fazendo um loop nessa fila. Quando a rede voltar a funcionar os arquivos serão gerados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde a framework 2.0 que consegues com o `GetIsNetworkAvailable()`:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

Para monitorizar as alterações ao IP ou se estás ligado ou não, usa os eventos da class NetworkChange:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged
```